# Best way to table data that may change monthly

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I currently use Excel to store all of my data but am learning SQL and Access by converting my Excel tables over to Access. I currently have a table with location names on the Y, month and year across the X and the Regional Manager name for each location/month. My employee data has their location, hire dates and term dates so I simply need to be able to identify who the Regional Manager is for a given date.

What would be the best way to table the location/monthly/regional data in order to determine which regional was effective for a particular location for any given date?

Comment: I am finding this website very helpful [http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/) as I am new to database design. Still don't know how I will design my database but I wanted to share this.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to purge all Excel type 2 dimensional thinking.

First you need a table with your locations. All tables should have a Primary Key. If your locations have some kind of number or short code, use that, if not use an auto-number. Add any location information as fields on that table. At least the name but you may also want address or other location specific information.

Then you do the same for the managers. A primary key to identify them, then maybe first name and last name and also hire and term dates. Term date can be NULL for current managers.

If each manager only manages one location during their tenure, you can add a field to the managers table with the primary key field from the locations table. If not things can get a bit more complicated.

Be aware that at this point you do not care or even think how the data "looks". You design your table structure based solely on what is the most efficient way to store and manipulate the information you want your database to handle.